# R: data.table, set first and last value of a group to NA

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to set the first and the last value in a group to NA. Here is an example:

```
DT <- data.table(v = rnorm(12), class=rep(1:3, each=4))
DT[, v[c(1,.N)] := NA , by=class]
```

But this is not working. How can I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the moment, the way to go about this would be to first extract the indices, and then do one assignment by reference.

```
idx = DT[, .(idx = .I[c(1L, .N)]), by=class]$idx
DT[idx, v := NA]
```

I'll try and add this example to the [Reference semantics](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) vignette.

Comment: The second command could be done with something like `set(DT,j="v",i=idx,value=NA)`, right? You'd know better than I whether that's faster.

Comment: @Frank, if you're doing it over and over, yes `set()` would be faster as it doesn't have the overhead of `[.data.table`. Shouldn't matter here.

Answer (score 4):

This may not be a one-liner, but it does have 'first' and 'last' in the code :)

```
> DT <- data.table(v = rnorm(12), class=rep(1:3, each=4))
> setkey(DT, class)
> classes = DT[, .(unique(class))]
> DT[classes, v := NA, mult='first']
> DT[classes, v := NA, mult='last']
> DT
          v class
 1:      NA     1
 2: -1.8191     1
 3: -0.6355     1
 4:      NA     1
 5:      NA     2
 6: -1.1771     2
 7: -0.8125     2
 8:      NA     2
 9:      NA     3
10:  0.2357     3
11:  0.3416     3
12:      NA     3
>
```

Order is also preserved for the non-key columns. I think that is a documented (committed to) feature.

Answer (score 1):

With a helper function it's easy

```
set.na = function(x,y) {x[y] = NA; x}
DT[, set.na(v,c(1,.N)) , by=class]
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to modify subsets of the data is to use `i` to define the subset. You cannot use `[` together with `:=`. Either create a temporary `i` as suggested by @David Arenburg or you can create the outcome vector yourself using a `c(NA, v[-c(1, .N)], NA)` construction.

```
DT[, v := c(NA, v[-c(1, .N)], NA)[1:.N], by = class]
```

However, you should also note that the row order can change when you e.g. set a new key or use any number of functions. So you should be very careful with this operation.